# Why finalize is not giving null pointer exception in the below code?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, finalize

Why the below code is not giving null pointer exception in the finalize method when the objects are made null??

```
class Person{  
public int a;
public void finalize(){
    //System.out.println("finalize called"+this.hashCode());
    System.out.println("finalize called"+this.a);
}  
public static void main(String[] args){  
    Person f1=new Person();  
    f1.a=10;
    Person f2=new Person();  
    f1=null;  
    f2=null;  
    System.gc();  
}}
```

O/P : finalize called0
finalize called10

Comment: Which part exactly should give NPE? If you're expecting `this` to be `null`, that's not possible at any time.

Comment: f1=null;  
    f2=null; Can you please explain , ie, if f1 and f2 are made null then why in finalize , no NPE is coming ?

Comment: Yes? You set 2 references to `null`. As you can see your `finalize()` method doesn't try to access either one of those (or do you see `f1` or `f2` in there?).

Comment: then why the output is :  finalize called0 finalize called10  ?

Comment: Because you set `f1.a = 10` so f1's finalize is outputting `finalize called10`.  f2.a == 0 (default value for an int) and it's finalize is outputting `finalize called0`

Comment: The object don't need to wait the variable to get out of scope to be gc'd.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are never made null, this is non-sense. References can be made null, and objects can be destroyed (as a consequence).

`f1` and `f2` are not objects, they are reference to objects. When you write `f1=null` that just means that this reference does not point to any object anymore and that the object that was previously pointed to has one reference less. The garbage collection (roughly) tracks all manipulations of references you make, and when objects are not referred anymore they are first put in some trash and then recycled or destroyed if needed, but object are existing even in that phase. When recycled/destroyed the machine will call `finalize` on it just before the recycling/destroying, then object exists at the time `finalize` is called (if not, how could `finalize` be called on the object?).

Answer (score 1):

Objects can't be made null, only references.

Just because you set `f1` and `f2` to null, doesn't mean that `finalize()` would throw a `NPE`. It's accessing the `this` reference which can never be null.

```
f1 --> Object <-- (implicit this accessible from inside the instance)
f2 --> Object <-- (--""--)

f1 = null; f2 = null;

       Object <-- (implicit this) previously f1 referred to this Object
       Object <-- (implicit this) previously f2 referred to this Object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person{  
public int a;
public void finalize(){
    //System.out.println("finalize called"+this.hashCode());
    System.out.println("finalize called"+this.a);
}  
public static void main(String[] args){  
    Person f1=new Person();  
    f1.a=10;
    Person f2=new Person();  
    f1=null;  
    f2=null;  
    System.out.println("f1 =" + f1 + " f2 = " + f2);
    System.gc(); 
    System.out.println("Below gc");

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(f1.a);// **here O/P - NPE**
}}
```

> **OUTPUT ->**
>
> f1 =null f2 = null
>
> Below gc
>
> finalize called0 finalize called10
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   basic.Person.main(Person.java:19)